# How to perform google authentication in ios without using google SDK and pods?

Tags: ios, swift

can anyone help me to do google authentication manually without using SDK as well as swift pods?

Comment: How do you want to do it manually means?

Comment: I think you want to authenticate using WebView

Comment: @SivajeeBattina Without using the predefined pods and sdk provided by google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you can use Google API with oAuth protocol: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

More information about how to use it [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this manually. You are expecting to get username and password of the user in textfields and to validate it using their API. This is not possible. You have to impelement this using their API's/frameworks.